# Переписать функцию на без цикла

Tags: for, smart-contract, solidity

Как реализовать код снизу, но без первого цикла?
Задача, каждый 4 re в цикле num даёт +1 num. Но в один цикл их пихать нельзя.

Функция работает так:
Есть num - количество срабатываний функции
есть re - сквозной счётчик, в котором сохранены все старые циклы num.

Я сделал так:

```
uint256 num = 35;
uint256 re = 3;
uint256 ever = 4;
uint256 tmp = 0;

for (uint256 i=0; i<num; i++) {
    re++;
    if (re % ever == 0) {
        tmp++;
    }
}

num = num + tmp;
for (uint256 i=0; i<num; i++) {
    func();
}
```

Ответы: num = 44, re = 38. Это правильные ответы.

Как реализовать всё то же самое, но без первого цикла? Типа такого, но это просто неправильный пример. Можно это сделать как-то с помощью формулы (x+y-1)/y.

```
uint256 tmp = (num.add(ever).sub(1)).div(ever);
num = num.add(tmp);
```

Вопрос решён. Спасибо @stanislav-volodarskiy и @mbo

**tmp = (re + num + ever) / ever - (re + ever) / ever;**

Comment: `Как реализовать всё то же самое` Для начала - правильно поставить задачу.

Comment: Я два раза прохожу цикл num. В первый раз для расчёта сколько раз re будет кратно ever и сохраняю результат. Второй раз уже для непосредственного выполнения функции. В теории можно как-то обойтись без первого цикла и рассчитать значения для num и re с помощью каких-то формул. Типа такого 
uint256 tmp = (num.add(ever).sub(1)).div(ever); 
num = num.add(tmp); 
Но это не верно

Comment: @stanislav-volodarskiy Если num=3, re=1, ever=4. Тогда ответ будет не верный. Должно быть num=4, re=4, а получается num=3, re=4. После каждого цикла я прибавляю к re+1 и проверяю на re % ever == 0. Соответственно на третий раз re = 4 и кратна ever и поэтому tmp+1

Comment: `tmp = (re + num + ever) / ever - (re + ever) / ever; re += num;`

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multiples` - количество кратных `x` в диапазоне `[a+1..b+1]` (включая границы).
`//` в Python - целочисленное деление, у вас будет простое деление `/` c целыми аргументами.

```
def multiples(a,b,x):
    l = (a + x) //x
    r = (b+1) // x
    return r - l + 1

num = 35
re = 3
ever = 4
t = num
num += multiples(re, re + num - 1, ever)
re += t
print(num, re)

>>  44 38
```

Comment: num = 40;
re = 10;
ever = 50;
Должно быть: num = 41, re = 50
А получается: num = 40, re = 50

Comment: почему так должно быть? в 40 числах от 10 до 49 нет кратных 50

Comment: Ну я же 40 раз прибавляю к re++. В итоге 40 + 10 = 50. И с этой кратности получаю +1. Если посмотреть мой первый пример, то я сначала делаю re++, а потом сравниваю (re % ever == 0). Не наоборот.

Comment: получается, надо сдвинуть на единицу значения

Comment: Но если сдвинуть, то остальные случаи, которые были верные, будут неверны

Comment: 35-3-4 по-прежнему дает 44-38.

Comment: Для каких данных ответ отличается от ожидаемого?